# Django 1.11 Pagination Markdown

Tags: python, django, pagination, markdown, django-pagination

I tried to paginate a very long string in Django by splitting it using an array which I successfully did however the [django-markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux%22django-markdown-deux%22)
 stopped working.

Here is how I implemented it:
models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
content = models.TextField()

def get_markdown(self):
    content = self.content
    markdown_text = markdown(content)
    return mark_safe(markdown_text)
```

views.py:

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):  #retrieve
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

#Detect the breaklines from DB and split the paragraphs using it
tempInstance = instance.content
PaginatedInstance = tempInstance.split("\r\n\r\n")

paginator = Paginator(PaginatedInstance, 5)  #set how many paragraph to show per page

page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

try:
    Paginated = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    Paginated = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    Paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    "instance": instance,
    "Paginated": Paginated,  #will use this to display the story instead of instance (divided string by paragraph)
}

return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

post_detail.html:

this is the one that works(without pagination):

```
{{ instance.get_markdown }}
```

this one works as plain text if I remove the .get_markdown and won't display anything if I put .get_markdown

```
{% for paginatedText in Paginated %}
{{ paginatedText.get_markdown }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `paginatedText` instance does not have a `get_markdown` method defined. Therefore, the template fails silently when you try to call it. You will need to use the `markdown` [filter](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux#markdown-template-filter) instead:

```
{% load markdown_deux_tags %}

{% for paginatedText in Paginated %}
{{ paginatedText|markdown }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it worked however there are times that the images that I insert using the markdown form is not showing.

Comment: whenever I add an image, the markdown form will generate this code: `![enter image description here][1]` on the location where I want the image to show and this:
` [1]: link-to-image.com\image.png` at the last part of the content which will not work unless I will copy ` [1]: link-to-image.com\image.png` next to `![enter image description here][1]`

Comment: Right. The pagninator is not Markdown aware. It assumes a much simpler plain text. You either need to format your Markdown in a way that the paginator can't break, or perhaps use a more sophisticated paginator. Personally, I would suggest converting the Markdown to HTML as an entire document, then paginate the HTML. However, that is outside the scope of this question.